# How can I control a whole Supervisor group at once?

Tags: supervisord

I have defined a non-homogenous Supervisor group. However I cannot control that group with the group name.

If I try, I get the following error:

```
$ supervisorctl start groupname
groupname ERROR (no such process)
```

I can, however, control a single elements of the group, for example `supervisorctl start groupname:programname`

Is it possible to control the entire group at once (start/stop/restart all programs in the group)? If so, how?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ah, you use `supervisorctl start groupname:*`

I discovered this by typing just `supervisorctl start` and being told:

```
Error: start requires a process name
start <name>        Start a process
start <gname>:*     Start all processes in a group
start <name> <name> Start multiple processes or groups
start all       Start all processes
```

...similarly for stop and restart.

Comment: They should really add this to the documentation.

Comment: The `*` is superfluous, `supervisorctl <command> <gname>:` is enough.